# Discretize weka attributes into specific intervals

Tags: weka, discretization

I need to discretize a column in weka. The column name is age. It has numerical attributes. for an example values from 2-90.

I need to perform discretization based on a specific range of values process to discretize Age attribute based on the following categories.

Youth: 15 -<=25,Adult:>25-<=64,Senior:>64

How this is possible in Weka?

How can I label and adjust the intervals

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Neither the [supervised](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/supervised/attribute/Discretize.html) nor the [unsupervised](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Discretize.html) version of the Discretize filter will allow you to do that.

But you can achieve that goal by building a filter chain using [MultiFilter](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/MultiFilter.html):

1. Use [MathExpression](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/MathExpression.html) to apply your manual binning strategy using nested `ifelse` expressions. Set the `ignoreRange` to the attribute that you want to convert and also select `invertSelection`. As `expression` use something like: `ifelse(A<=25,0,ifelse(A<=64,1,2))` (25 or lower will be turned into `0`, 64 or lower into `1` and the rest into `2`).
2. Convert the generated bin values into nominal labels using [NumericToNominal](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NumericToNominal.html). Define the attribute you want to convert in `attributeIndices`.
3. Finally, rename the numeric-looking labels `0,1,2` into more meaningful ones using [RenameNominalValues](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/RenameNominalValues.html). Specify the attribute you want to update in `selectedAttributes` and use `0:Youth,1:Adult,2:Senior` as `valueReplacements`.

The following `MultiFilter` setup converts the 7th attribute in a dataset in such a fashion (just copy it and paste it in the Weka Explorer via the right-click menu):

```
weka.filters.MultiFilter -F "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.MathExpression -E ifelse(A<=25,0,ifelse(A<=64,1,2)) -V -R 7" -F "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal -R 7" -F "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.RenameNominalValues -R 7 -N 0:Youth,1:Adult,2:Senior" -S 1
```